# Explode a result and Assign them to a Variables

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have an input field, which consist of different email addressess. I want to be able to loop through this input on submit, and assign each to a variable so, i could use them for processing. See my code and tell me where I am missing it:

```
<input type="email" name="m" placeholder-"Enter Email address separated by (;)"/>
<input type="submit" name="sbt" value="Submit"/>

<?php
if($_POST['sbt']){
$myMail = $_POST['m'];
$res = explode(";",$myMail);
foreach($res as $ml=>$value){
echo '$us'.$ml."=".$value.";<br/>"; 
}   
}
?>

I want the result to be :$us0 = ade.yemi@yahoo.com;
$us1 = ade.yemi@yahoo.com;
$us2 = nifemi.ola@gmail.com;
but it is show undefined variables for $us0;$us1;$us2.
```

Please help or is there is a better way, as i want to make use of these    variable for CC aspect in phpmailer.

Comment: try this in your foreach loop: `$vname = 'us' . $ml; ${$vname} = $value;` then you should have $us0, $us1... for later use in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This row: `$res = explode(";",$myMail);` will give you an array with all the email addresses, like:

```
[
   0 => 'some-address@example.com', 
   1 => 'another@example.com', 
   ...
].
```

Why not just use that array?

Fetch the e-mail addresses like this, where you need them:

```
$phpMailer->addCC($res[0]);
$phpMailer->addCC($res[1]); // Or what the syntax for PHPMailer is...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly with the use of the array directly